# Nash equilibrium as the number of players goes to infinity

Tags: pr.probability, nash-equilibrium

I'm trying to find results that characterize the Nash equilibrium in a multi-player game as the number of players $N$ goes to infinity.

The game could be symmetrical, or maybe there could be a paramemeter $a_j$ describing the $j$-th player's actions and for $N \rightarrow \infty$ we know it comes from a known distribution $p(a)$.

To be more exact:

1. can the strategy computation be simplified when considering the $N \rightarrow \infty$ limit ?
2. are there circumstances where the game parameters can be normalized with $N$ to obtain a "player continuum" limit result ?

Are there any examples of specific games where the above questions are addressed ?

Comment: Specific games where this question is addressed are certainly mean field games.

Comment: Thank you ! Very helpful.

Comment: In case you have not already found it, these notes of Cardaliaguet are a great (and free) introduction to mean field games, particularly Section 2 dealing with static games: https://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/~cardaliaguet/MFGcours2018.pdf

Comment: @Dan Thanks, I actually came across his 2013 notes, these are probably more up to date :)